# How can I make names in a mercurial revision history consistent?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with committer name change in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950792/how-to-deal-with-committer-name-change-in-mercurial)

On a new install, I forgot to set my username reasonably in my hg client. As a result, the last few commits have me listed as "`Billy`", rather than the "`Billy O'Neal <billy.oneal@example.com>`" like I have been using.

Is there a way I can change these to make them consistent?

Comment: This is just a joke: "How can I adjust history to suit my needs.  Sounds like an election year".

Comment: @DwB: Lol -- seriously though. I don't want to change what happened in the commit; just the name associated with it.

Comment: I'm no mercurial expert, but a quick browse of [Mercurial: the definitive guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/) -- which is dated 2009 -- shows no way to change the name of the committer post commit.  You might need to write an extension.

Comment: @BillyONeal: have you pushed to anywhere? If you have, you can't modify it at all. If you haven't, it's possible (though not friendly, but that's an article of Mercurial's design).

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - sorry, even published repo can be edited (technically),   on pull/push into old clones they just get anonymous branch

Comment: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3950827/960558) with full command-line for convert for same question [How to deal with committer name change in Mercurial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950792/how-to-deal-with-committer-name-change-in-mercurial)

Comment: @LazyBadger: when I say "you can't", I don't mean that strictly it's impossible, but that it's unmanageable, unworkable, undesirable and werry nasty with unpleasant side-effects aplenty and the probability of breaking things.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan - **even I** see difference between "impossible" and "terrrible bad solution", sorry. And re-publish **is manageable, workable** with *side effects and headache* and only **undesirable and werry nasty**. In *this form* only I'll see  real facts and status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to edit history with extensions like [mq](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) and [convert](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension), but if you have pushed the commits, you'd have to edit every clone of your repository as well.  If you are a small group of users that may be possible, but otherwise it is too late.