# Changing author name in mercurial repo

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am trying this

[How to deal with committer name change in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950792/how-to-deal-with-committer-name-change-in-mercurial)

and using this command to chnage the author names in mercurial repo

`hg convert --authors authors.convert.list mysite mysite2`

now this works fine but when i go to mysite 2 then i see no files in there but only `.hg` folder.

I remeber i did that before few months ago but don't know if i am missing something. Do i manually need to copy the files in `mysite2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `hg update` in `mysite2`. After the conversion, the working copy is at the special `null` revision, which is the revision with number -1.

Comment: i have convered that before , at that time the new repo had all the files as well. i didn't had to run hg update at that time. why now

Comment: Check what `hg summary` says in `mysite2`. I'm sure the repo "has all the files", they're just not checked out. Use `hg update` for that.

Comment: hg summary says same as in mian repo but when i go inside that folder there are no folders except `.hg`

Comment: If you see the expected history with `hg log`, then you can use `hg update` to checkout the files. The `hg summary` command should have told you something like "no revision checked out" and "update: N new changesets (update)".